# Solve integral equations

Tags: calculus

It is posible to calcultate the kernel f(x,t) knowing g[t]
$$\int_a^b f(x,t) \, dx=g(t)$$ i used laplacetrasnform for the volterra equation but do not work
thanks

Answer (score 2):

I don't see why f is necessarily unique. Any $f(x,t) = g(t)h(x) $ with $\int_a^b h(x) dx = 1$ is a solution